# how i can plot the multiple condition present in one data using one plot script?

Tags: r, loops, boxplot

I am using R studio to plot boxplot.

My data looks like --

```
level  Q9HC84       P02768
2      232742108.4  32822363539
2      2886647577   25661800126
1      629319882.2  26745385141
1      1293306218   2173862517
0      632315638.5  994599604.8
0      221394201.3  1659282642
```

Here is the command I am using to plot a graph:

```
boxplot(Q9HC84 ~ level ,  data = x , xlab = "Cases", ylab = "Protein",
        main = "Q9HC84" , notch = FALSE, 
        varwidth = TRUE, names = c("C","T","O"))
```

This shows me a perfect result that is what I want.
But I have 90 proteins name in the data and I want to change this script in a manner that it will generate boxplot for each protein separately.

Same thing i did with lineplot that was easy, but in boxplot it's hard to find how to apply loop. I tried this script ----

```
for(i in 3:5)
{
  x = data.frame(proteomics$level)
  y = data.frame(proteomics[i])
boxplot(y ~ x ,  xlab = "Cases", ylab = "Metabolite",
        main = "Q9HC84" , notch = FALSE, 
        varwidth = TRUE, names = c("Control","Tobacco","OSCC"))

}
```

can anybody help me ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I find it hard to see the proteins in your data. Can you point them out?

Comment: Q9HC84  and P02768 are the proteins id . header name of column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to create boxplots with this many groups while still having the plot being readable.

```
# generate example data
set.seed(1)
np <- 20
level <- rep(1:3, times=c(4, 5, 5))
pnames <- replicate(
  np, paste(c(sample(LETTERS, 1), sample(c(0:9, LETTERS), 5)), collapse="")
)
prot <- round(runif(np*length(level), 2213942000, 328223635400), 1)
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(level, matrix(prot, ncol=np)))
colnames(x)[-1] <- pnames


# reshape to long format
library(reshape2)
x.long <- melt(x, id.vars="level")
x.long$level <- c("C","T","O")[x.long$level]

# plot vertically, level + variable
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", mar=c(3.5, 3, 0.5, 0.5))
col <- c("orange", "cornflowerblue", "purple")
boxplot(value ~ level + variable, data=x.long, cex=0.5, cex.axis=0.5, las=2, 
  col=col, border=col, boxwex=0.5)

# plot horizontally, variable + level
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", mar=c(2, 3.5, 0.5, 0.5))
col <- rep(c("orange", "cornflowerblue", "purple"), 
  each=length(unique(x.long$variable)))
boxplot(value ~ variable + level, data=x.long, cex=0.5, cex.axis=0.5, las=1,
  horizontal=TRUE, col=col, border=col, boxwex=0.5)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much . its really working properly for my data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions:

Assuming your data (slightly simplified) look like this (with three proteins, but that number can obviously be extended):

```
df <- data.frame(
  level = c(2,2,1,1,0,0),
  prot1 = c(rnorm(6)+1),
  prot2 = c(rnorm(6)),
  prot3 = c(rnorm(6)-1)
)
```

you can re-structure the data in such a way that the protein names form one column and the values they have form another column:

```
df_new <- data.frame(
  level = rep(c(2,2,1,1,0,0),3),
  protein_names = c(rep("prot1",6),rep("prot2",6),rep("prot3",6)),
  protein_values = c(df$prot1, df$prot2, df$prot3)
)
df_new
```

The first solution is an R base solution:
This line of code plots all boxplots within a single frame:

```
boxplot(df_new$protein_values ~ df_new$level+df_new$protein_names)
```

This `for` loop plots a separate frame for each protein:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for(i in unique(df_new$protein_names)){
  boxplot(df_new[df_new$protein_names==i,]$protein_values ~   df_new[df_new$protein_names==i,]$level)
}
```

The second solution is a `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_new, aes(as.factor(level), protein_values)) +
geom_boxplot() +
facet_grid(.~protein_names)
```

[image]